# How to preserve a language using javascript json

Tags: javascript, json, multilingual

I use the following code in main.js and index.html for changing the language. It works to change the content of all three languages after pressing the buttons. However, the language will be returned to "ENG" every time the user changes the page.  Is there a way to preserve the language the user selected at the very last time? Thank you.

main.js

```
/* Lang.json newly added */
$.getJSON("Lang.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // this will show the info it in firebug console
});

$(document).ready(function() {
// The default language is English
  var lang = "ENG";
  $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
  });
});

// get/set the selected language
$(".translate").click(function() {
  var lang = $(this).attr("id");
  $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<button class="translate" id="ENG">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="assets/img/eng.png" /></a> 
</button>
<button class="translate" id="CHT">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="assets/img/cht.png" /></a>
</button>
<button class="translate" id="CHS">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;"><img src="assets/img/chs.png" /></a>
</button>
```

Comment: use cookies to store the last selected language, on loading, check for the selected language in cookies.

Comment: Thanks, Akhil, do you have any code for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the localStorage to preserve the values. Check the below I have added comments.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// The default language is English
  // Get the lang value from localStorage, if not set use the default value 'ENG'
  var lang = window.localStorage.getItem('lang') || "ENG";
  $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
  });

   // get/set the selected language
  $(".translate").click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr("id");
    // Save the lang value to localStorage to preserve
    window.localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
    $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It could not display any language. What will be the problem?

Comment: oh my bad, I just updated the answer, i meant localStorage instead of localStore. Can you check now?

Comment: The last selected could not been saved.

Comment: @user243069, Can you check now?, if it still does not work, Can you create some sample running in jsfiddle or similar environment so that I can see what the behaviour?

Comment: Np! Glad to hear. If no other related concern, can you mark it answered?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for changing lenguages with image of 2 flags and saving the variable lenguage in the cookies so if you change between pages it will be saved.
lenguage.js

```js
var x= decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);


$('[lang="es"]').hide();
if(x==("lenguage=es")){
  $('[lang="es"]').show();
  $('[lang="en"]').hide();
}

$('#en').click(function() {
    $('[lang="es"]').hide();
    $('[lang="en"]').show();
    document.cookie="lenguage=en"
});

$('#es').click(function() {
    $('[lang="es"]').show();
    $('[lang="en"]').hide();
    document.cookie="lenguage=es"

});
```

```html
HTML file, change img files.

            </div>
              <a class="navbar-brand flag logo" href="#">
                <img src="img/esRect.png"  class="flag"alt="" id="es">
              </a>
              <a class="navbar-brand flag" href="#">
                <img src="img/ukRect.png"  class="flag"alt="" id="en">
              </a>
            </div>
            
             <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/lenguage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```