# Displaing element that should not be displayed in select html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am using this way to have 2 languages in my html page using JavaScript described in this issue:
[stack overflow language using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550090/how-to-preserve-a-language-using-javascript-json/67620544#67620544)

Now I have to put *lang* in the select so when I choose one language the other element with *lang* disappears but I can see both of them.

```
<div class="col">
   <select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3 " id="mySelect" onchange="brightness()" >
          <option selected lang="en">Brightness</option>
          <option selected lang="es">Luminosidad</option>
          <option value="0.1">1</option>
          <option value="0.2">2</option>
          <option value="0.3">3</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

If I do this it is working but I want the text to be included inside the select and options:

```
<p lang="en">Brightness</p>
<p lang="es">Luminosidad</p>
<select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3 " id="mySelect" onchange="brightness()" >
<option value="0.1">1</option>
<option value="0.2">2</option>
<option value="0.3">3</option>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the select option for 1st and second lang, You need to add value to them. Then target the value to pass your javascript function. E.g: if value == "en", you do something, and if value == "es", do another thing.